# VB.NET: How to write If Not expression?

Tags: vb.net

This is ok in VB.NET: `If(hash.add(Numbers[index]))`
However how do you write the following in VB.NET: `If(!hash.add(Numbers[index]))`

Comment: What is hash?  What is numbers?  What is your intent?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ it will help you convert c# to VB and vice versa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
If(NOT hash.add(Numbers[index]))
```